# 10.4.10-MariaDB Column 'authentication_string' is not updatable

Tags: mariadb-10.4

So I just installed mariadb in a new server as always, but it seems none of my commands I used to set root password and allow remote root logins work anymore and googling isn't helping me much.

```
mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"


mysql -u root -e "use mysql;update user set authentication_string=password('password') where user='root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"


mysql -u root -e "use mysql;UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

This is what I used on my ssh terminal to allow remote access to root using a password. How can I do this in this new version?

Answer (score 3):

You are suppose to run `mysql_upgrade` command for Mariadb instance. Command is as following :

```
mysql_upgrade [--force] [--user=# --password 
  --host=hostname --port=# --socket=#
  --protocol=tcp|socket|pipe|memory 
  --verbose]
```

Comment: What do you mean? I had to revert back to mysql 5.7 because of the downtime.

Comment: This upgrade will check the structure and modify it. You can execute it with no downtime, if no temporal columns are there in your database. Because MySQL_upgrade will convert temporal columns which might take time depending on your db size.

Comment: But before installing the mariadb server I purged my previous database with `apt purge mysql* -y` and removed anything with sql in my system.

Comment: Okay , that means you are restore database using mysqldump after upgrading to mariadb. Fair enough, you can try mysql_upgrade online then it will not take much time.

Comment: It worked for me, but won't worked in MariaDB. No more option, you need re-create the user with same password & privileges.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
SET PASSWORD FOR user@localhost =  PASSWORD('passwordUwant') ;
```

the cause of this problem is because user is a 'view' now
source: https://mariadb.com/kb/pt-br/set-password/

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-password/